# SFINAE or enable_if to check if non-type template parameter is even or odd

Tags: c++, sfinae

```
template <unsigned int n>
class myclass {};
```

Is there a way (preferably using SFINAE, that is `std::enable_if`) to get compilation error when `n` is odd? I need it to be even.

Comment: Have you tried `static_assert`?

Comment: simply static_assert inside of template. You'd need SFINAE for selecting something , not for error generation. NAE - not an error :P

Comment: I will surely use `static_assert` if SFINAE not possible. But maybe it is possible?

Comment: @user3600124 `static_assert` is a better solution in this case. You will get a clear error message if the condition is violated. Using SFINAE will produce an error message that is very likely to be confusing.

Comment: Why the insistence on SFINAE? Where are the overloads being discarded? Or a specialisation? SFINAE is about *soft errors*.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it with SFINAE, use partial template specialization and don't define the base class.

e.g.:

```cpp
template <unsigned int n, typename _ = void>
class myclass;

template <unsigned int n>
class myclass<n,std::enable_if_t<n%2==0>> {};
```

then you'll get a compile-time error if you try to instantiate `myclass` with an odd number.
([example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wc3896dqT))

---

Another approach would be to just use a `static_assert` to check if the number is even, this has the additional benefit that you can specify a message instead of getting a cryptic SFINAE error:

```
template <unsigned int n>
class myclass {
    static_assert(n%2==0, "n must be even");
};
```

([example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7r7jjKvMo))

---

If you want you can also combine the two variants above, giving you an SFINAE solution with a nice error message:

```cpp
template <unsigned int n, typename _ = void>
class myclass {
    static_assert(n!=n, "n must be even");
};

template <unsigned int n>
class myclass<n,std::enable_if_t<n%2==0>> {
    /* code */
};
```

([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/79376Gax4))

---

In case you're using a c++ version before C++14 you'll need to replace

```cpp
std::enable_if_t<?>
```

with

```cpp
typename std::enable_if<?>::type
```

in the above examples.

Answer (score 3):

> preferably using SFINAE

If you need SFINAE, I suggest creating a type trait:

```
template<unsigned n>
static constexpr bool is_even_v = n % 2 == 0;

template <unsigned int n, std::enable_if_t<is_even_v<n>, int> = 0>
class myclass {};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TTdvoEb1r)